# Updating multiple fields of a model in MongoDB with Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, struct

In rust, I want to update an entire model, instead of writing a query that `$set` for multiple fields, like that:

```rust
use mongodb::{bson, bson::doc, Client, Collection};

let collection: Collection<User> =
               client.database(DB_NAME).collection(users::REPOSITORY_NAME);
let filter = doc! {"email": new_user_copy.email};
let new_user_bson = match bson::to_bson(&new_user_copy) {
    bson::Document(doc) => doc,
    _ => unreachable!(),
};
let update = doc! {"$set": new_user_bson};
let result = collection.update_one(filter, update, None).await;
```

But I have the following error at compilation:

> error[E0532]: expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found struct `Document`
> --> src/controllers/users.rs:82:17
> |
> 82 |                 Document(doc) => doc,
> |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> |
> ::: /Users/adrien/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bson-2.6.1/src/document.rs:63:1
> |
> 63 | pub struct Document {
> | ------------------- `Document` defined here
> |
> help: use struct pattern syntax instead
> |
> 82 |                 Document { inner } => doc,
> |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> help: consider importing one of these items instead
> |
> 1  | use crate::controllers::users::bson::Bson::Document;
> |
> 1  | use crate::controllers::users::bson::RawBson::Document;
> |
> 1  | use crate::controllers::users::bson::RawBsonRef::Document;
> |
> 1  | use mongodb::options::UpdateModifications::Document;

Answer (score 2):

You can update multiple fields in a single `$set` definition, the error you're getting is because you're using the `$and` operator in the update body, which is not allowed.

Just write your `$set` like this:

```
let update = doc! {"$set": {"first_name": new_user_copy.first_name, "last_name": new_user_copy.last_name}};
```

This will update both the first name and the last name fields.

---

To update all fields contained by the input you can just pass it to the `$set` operator, like so:

```
let update = doc! {"$set": new_user_copy};
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to update all fields of a User struct at once without adding every field one by one?

Comment: yes, i will edit my answer.

Comment: I have a compilation error: ```the trait bound `Bson: std::convert::From<User>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`:```, what do I need to do to be able to put a User in the doc macro?

Comment: unfortunately i'm less familiar with Rust structures,  but this seems like a simple type casting issue.

Comment: `mongodb` uses the `bson` crate for serialization/deserialization, which relies on `serde`. In order to use a strongly-typed data structure with the `doc!` macro, you need to derive `serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}` on the struct. See [here](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/#modeling-bson-with-strongly-typed-data-structures).